# Call javascript function in parent window from child ajax

Tags: php, ajax, function, parent-child

been working on a new site, and run into a problem.

I have an ajax loader on my main page, which loads a script every second to check if a background process is completed (usually 20 seconds-ish)

But, once the ajax script has executed (20 seconds later) it still refreshes every second.

I need to redirect the parent page to a new url, once the ajax script has finished its job.

My ajax code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

try{
    // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
    ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
} catch (e){
    // Internet Explorer Browsers
    try{
        ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    } catch (e) {
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e){
            // Something went wrong
            alert("Your browser broke!");
            return false;
        }
    }
}
// Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=ajaxRequest.responseText;
    }
}
ajaxRequest.open("GET", "code/timer.php?file='.$file.'", true);
ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
</script>



<script type="text/javascript">
function forward(){

location.href=\'http://domain/newpage.html\';


}

function setTimer(){

set = setInterval( "myFunction()", 1000 );

}
</script>
```

the backslashes in forward(); are because my code is echoed from php.

i have tried a few codes, but the main one that should work (in child ajax element) is:

```
window.opener.forward();
```

would be greatful of any help you guys can provide... thanks

Comment: please define `parent.page`, are you using frames or popups?

Comment: im not using either. there is just a page (index.html) that loads the ajax script, and displays the result. once a condition is met in the ajax script, i cant stop the parent page (index.html) from refreshing the ajax script

Answer (score 0):

opener is only available in windows opened with javascript, call simply

```
forward();
```

but you should use another name for the function, there is a predefined method [`window.forward()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.forward)

Comment: have changed name of function, and called it from child script... do i need to put the forwarder script on the parent or child page?

Comment: there is only 1 page, neither parent nor child, at least you've written this in your comment